# How filter java stream by a list of strings without using a for loop

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List<LogEntry>` that I need to filter out from the list every log that is not on `Level.SEVERE`.
And in addition I have a List of whitelisted logs that need to be filtered too.
These logs are contains only partial message so I have to use `contains()` to identified them.

My code looks like this:

```
LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
List<LogEntry> logEntriesList = logEntries.getAll();

Stream<LogEntry> filtered =
    logEntriesList.stream()
                  .filter(log -> log.getLevel().equals(Level.SEVERE));
    
for (String whitelisted : whitelistedLogs) {
    filtered = filtered.filter(log -> !log.getMessage().contains(whitelisted));
}
```

Is there any way to avoid this for loop and get the same result?

Comment: I am reverting the edit as the answer need not be posted as part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you filter those with `SEVERE` log level, then filter those which contains at least one whitelisted message:

```java
logEntriesList.stream()
              .filter(log -> log.getLevel().equals(Level.SEVERE))
              .filter(log -> whitelistedLogs.stream().noneMatch(wl -> log.getMessage().contains(wl)))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't worked for me at start, but it gives me a solid direction how to do it. Thanks :)

Comment: @Tal you may update the answer here. No need to update the question with the answer.

Comment: @Tal Also it is better (more readable) to use `noneMatch(condition)` instead of `allMatch( !condition)` I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If whitelisted logs are constant, instead of list, you could create a regex from them one time. That way you could:

```
filtered = filtered.filter(log -> !log.getMessage().matches(whitelisted_regex));
```

Comment: I don't think that regex will be helpful in my case.
The strings of the whitelisted logs are not related to each other.

Comment: If you can give example of whitelisted logs and actual logs, at least few of them, I could try to tell you.